# Installation of an IDE for Java EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I would like to install an IDE for Java EE.

The problem is that I can't find a version of Eclipse or Netbeans that's compatible with JRE 7u51 (64bit), which is the one I have already installed.

I'm working with it in Eclipse (for Java SE not Java EE).

Can someone help me to find the suitable one?

Comment: The Eclipse JEE code is fine with JRE 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can download any IDE. Both will be compatible with your defined system pre-requisits. It's fine installing either **Eclipse IDE for Java EE development** OR **Netbeans IDE for Java EE development**!

You better have a look at these links for downloading the IDE's :-

[Eclipse Downloads for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip)

[Netbeans IDE Download-Java EE](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)